# executable kubelogin failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I'm using an Kubernetes server with API version (1.25.2) . When I try to do a kubectl command getting the below error

```
TRONBQQ2:~$ kubectl get nodes
error: unknown flag: --environment
error: unknown flag: --environment
error: unknown flag: --environment
error: unknown flag: --environment
error: unknown flag: --environment
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin failed with exit code 1
```

From the same terminal I'm able to access the Kubernetes server with version 1.23.12.

Is this due to an old kubectl clieint version?.

```
TRONBQQ2:~$ kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
TRONBQQ2:~$ sudo apt-get install -y kubectl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

kubectl is already the newest version (1.19.4-00).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 313 not upgraded.

I even tried to upgrade the [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-linux) . Even after upgrade, version remains in v1.19.4. Not sure this is the reason for the above mentioned error

Comment: Have you run  "az aks get-credentials -g rgname -n clustername" ?

Comment: yes,  I ran it ...Authentication is working fine. But couldn't run kubectl against it.

Comment: This seems like something that might be configured in your `~/.kube/config` file.  It doesn't especially seem like a programming problem, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to check whether the the following command is printing the  below options.

```
>>>kubelogin -h

Login to azure active directory and populate kubeconfig with AAD tokens

Usage:
  kubelogin [flags]
  kubelogin [command]

Available Commands:
    completion         Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
   convert-kubeconfig convert kubeconfig to use exec auth module
   get-token          get AAD token
  help               Help about any command
  remove-tokens      Remove all cached tokens from filesystem

 Flags:
     -h, --help          help for kubelogin
     --logtostderr   log to standard error instead of files (default true)
 -v, --v Level       number for the log level verbosity
  --version       version for kubelogin
```

It seems I was having a different kubelogin and missed the above specified Command Options. So I installed the new version of kubelogin using

```
 az aks install-cli
```

If that doesn't work, then you can refer "[image]" to get the kubelogin brew package

Also export the below path

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Once the kubelogin is available , run the below command to convert your  KUBECONFIG

```
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig --kubeconfig ./kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

For China users, you need to check your `.kube/config` file, be sure the `--environment` argument is in place.
E.g.

```yaml
users:
- name: your cluster name
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - get-token
      - --login
      - devicecode
      - --server-id
      - xxxx
      - --client-id
      - xxxx-xxxx
      - --tenant-id
      - xxxx-xxxx
      - --environment
      - AzureChinaCloud
```

Answer (score -1):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

I did the following issue to resolve the issue

This issue will occur due to the version, we have to upgrade the latest version

I have set the subscription id to AKS cluster using below command

```
az account set --subscription "subscription_id"
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <rg-name> --name <cluster-name> --admin
```

[image]

My current AKS version is 1.23.12

[image]

My Kubectl version is

```
kubectl version --client
```

[image]

This error will occur based on the kube/config file and the config file should be exist

```
cd ~/.kube/.
vi config
```

I have the config file configured we won't get any error

Below is my config file

```
apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: XXXXXXXXX
        server: https:cluster123.hcp.azmk8s.io.443
      name: cluster123
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: cluster123
        user: clusterUser_Alldemorg_cluster123
      name: komali-test
    current-context: cluster123
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
        client-certificate: XXXXXX
        client-key-Data: XXXXXXX
```

I have followed the below commands to access the kubectl commands

```
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - I am suffering from the main issue described.  Do you manually need to change/update the C:\Users\arran\.kube\config file? My config file automatically gets created upon executing the `az aks get-credentials -g myresourcegroup -n aksclustername`

Answer (score -1):

Check KubeLogin is installed on your ubuntu machine:

```
kubelogin
```

Try this command to connect with AKS cli

```
az aks install-cli
```

If you face permission denied in ubuntu machine user's:

```
sudo az aks install-cli
```

Then you will get a Kubelogin configured in your local machine.
try the below mentioned command:

```
kubectl get pods
```

it will provide you a line of text with a url and code:

> https://microsoft.com/devicelogin

and access code **"xcasdafsaf"** . The above Url will be re-directing to microsoft AD login. There you needs to login with you azure active directary login credentials. This will enable the KubeCtl access to your terminal or shell.